# How can this Ruby code be translated to Redis command line?

Tags: ruby, redis

```
results=$redis.zrevrangebyscore(key(:feed), "(#{max}", "-inf", :limit => [0, limit], :with_scores => scores)
```

and

```
results=$redis.zrevrange key(:feed), 0, count
```

What would these look like in redis-cli command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ZREVRANGEBYSCORE 'key(feed)' 'max' -inf WITHSCORES limit 0 'limit'
ZREVRANGE 'key(feed)' 0 'count'
```